# appGyver Steroids SQLite Cordova Plugin

Tags: sqlite, cordova, cordova-plugins, steroids

I'm using steroids by appgyver (update to latest version which includes supersonic as well) to develop my app.

I'm confused about the SQLite plugin. First they supported and included it, then they remove it, then they say that it will not work unless you configure the custom build (and there is no much documentation about that)...

I have a very simple application: textarea and button. When you click the button you insert intto the database the value.

According to the docs https://github.com/brodysoft/Cordova-SQLitePlugin

I'm using var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name : "mydb"});

to open the database. I have the scanner app updated on both android and ios. The result is that in IOS works fine while in Android I get this error: "Cannot read property 'openDatabase' of undefined".

My question is: for IOS the app will stop working once deployed on the appstore?

Why it's working with IOS Scanner? Is it supposed to work? I understood they removed SQLIte support. I don't understand. Then, cause in IOS works, why in Android is not working?

Moreover, how to include SQLite plugin in a steroid project? Anyone was suffesfuul with that? I love appgyver, they did a wonderful job with steroids and supersonic, but... for this SQLite plugin and related support (even an example would do) I'm a bit concerned regarding my decision to go with steroids and not with xamarin for example.

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1):

AppGyver dev here! You need to include the SQLite plugin as a custom plugin to your app using our Build Service, and then build a stand-alone app: http://docs.appgyver.com/tooling/build-service/

The SQLite plugin is included in the iOS App Store Scanner for preview purposes, so that's the reason it's working on iOS and not on Android. This is actually something we're removing soon, so sorry for the confusion.